# Stationary solutions

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, differential-equations

I would like to know what stationary solutions means in this classical mechanics problem: On a vertical plane there is a rotating massless infinitely long rod with a fixed point $O$ on the plane. On one side with distance $l$ there is a point mass $m_1$ on the rod. On the other side a spring connects $O$ with a point mass $m_2$. The distance between $O$ and $m_2$ is $r$.[image]

The spring constant k, satisfies  $$\frac{k}{g}=\frac{m_2^2}{2m_1l},$$ where $g$ is the gravitational acceleration of earth. The potential energy of the spring is $$\frac{kr^2}{2}.$$

After calculating the Lagrangian in polar coordinates, where $\varphi$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the rod$$\mathcal{L}(r,\dot{r},\varphi,\dot{\varphi})=\frac{1}{2}\left(m_1l^2\dot{\varphi}^2+m_2r^2\dot{\varphi}^2+m_2\dot{r}^2\right)-\frac{kr^2}{2}-g\sin{(\varphi)}(m_1l-m_2r),$$
I derived the two Euler-Lagrange equations
$$m_2\ddot{r}=m_2\dot{\varphi}^2r-kr+m_2g\sin{(\varphi)}, \tag{$r$}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\left(m_1l^2+m_2r^2\right)\dot{\varphi}\right)=-g\cos{(\varphi)}\left(m_1l-m_2r\right)\tag{$\varphi$}.$$
Now what are the stationary solutions to this problem? I don't want a solution, just an explanation what requirements a stationary solution must have. I can't think of any way this system is not moving with time except when the rod is vertical and not rotating anymore but this seems trivial..

Comment: *Stationary* has its usual meaning of *not moving* or *not changing with time*. In this problem it probably means that while the rod rotates the distance $r$ does not change.

Comment: That is not something I can solve for. The equations $(r)$,$(\varphi)$ do not get a lot easier (at least I failed to solve them).  I got

Comment: (with \$$$$
0=m_2r\dot{\varphi}+\sin{\varphi}m_2g-kr
$$
$$
(m_1l^2+m_2r^2)\ddot{\varphi}=(m_2r-m_1l)g\cos{\varphi}
$$